# Set charsequence size after declaration

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, charsequence

Ok, so I have something like:

```
CharSequence[] lines;
```

and then I want to set its size in an Android Dialog click, like:

```
lines = new CharSequence[131];
```

but it will end up empty.

I need to populate a dialog with its values, but if I would do something like:

```
CharSequence[] lines = new CharSequence[131];
```

in the beginning and then populating it, then I will get an error when scrolling because of the **null** options in the dialog (no of options < 131).

I am kind of a beginner in Java.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if its empty, then you must to insert to it

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Hi, please check the edit. :)

Comment: can you post your code including data insert to that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. You check when a cell is empty `lines[i] != null`
2. You fill `lines` with data using `Arrays.fill(lines, new CharSequence()`) [see the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))